# How to grab all variables in a post (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, post

How to grab all variables in a post (PHP)?
I don't want to deal with `$_POST['var1']; $_POST['var2']; $_POST['var3']; ...`
I want to echo all of them in one shot.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you really just want to print them, you could do something like:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Alternatively, you could interact with them individually doing something like:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //do something
    echo $key . ' has the value of ' . $value;
}
```

but whatever you do.. please filter the input. SQL Injection gives everyone sleepless nights.

Comment: Or XSS. This sentence is here to make the comment greater than 15 characters.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the POST values as variables in your script, you can use the extract function, e.g.

```
extract ( $_GET );
```

or

```
extract ( $_GET, EXTR_IF_EXISTS );
```

There are several flags you can use (check the manual); this one restricts extraction to variables already defined.

You can also use the import_request_variables function.

Cheers

Jeff

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: I hate the `var_dump` ugly output unless `xdebug` is installed and enabled.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($_POST); 
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this function in a loop.
extract ( $_GET );