# PHP: Possible to automatically get all POSTed data?

Tags: php, forms, post

Simple question: Is it possible to get all the data POSTed to a page, even if you don't know all the fields?

For example, I want to write a simple script that collects any POSTed data and emails it. I can foresee that the fields in the form are likely to change a lot over time, and so to save myself some time in the long run, I was wondering if I could write something that automatically gathered everything?

Is it possible?

Comment: ofcourse just use the global arrays $_POST, $_GET, $_Ser.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grab all variables in a post (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058336/how-to-grab-all-variables-in-a-post-php)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Sure. Just walk through the `$_POST` array:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: @Django Reinhardt Note that non-checked checkboxes do not appear in the `$_POST` array so if you use checkboxes, you will need to handle them differently by using `isset` for example.

Comment: what if there is a file , will it come with it

Comment: Can the same be used for $_GET?

Answer (score 50):

No one mentioned **Raw Post Data**, but it's good to know, if posted data has no key, but only value, use [Raw Post Data](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php):

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

**PHP Man:**

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use simply

```
     $input_data = $_POST;
```

or [extract()](http://php.net/extract) may be useful for you.

Comment: `extract($_POST)` will mimic `register_globals`. Don't do that.

Comment: @netcoder; i just suggest him that it can be useful; it is an option too. and will u please give me an example to make ur comments valuable.

Comment: Using `extract` on an unfiltered/unsanitized user supplied data is super, super bad idea.  Do yourself a favor and don't bake insecurity into your code.

Answer (score 5):

All posted data will be in the $_POST superglobal.

http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't want any special formatting: yes.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    $body .= $key . ' -> ' . $value . '<br>';
```

Obviously, more formatting would be necessary, however that's the "easy" way.  Unless I misunderstood the question.

You could also do something like this (and if you like the format, it's certainly easier):

```
$body = print_r($_POST, true);
```

Comment: +1 The latter suggestion (`$body = print_r($_POST, true);`) worked for me as the simplest without having to iterate through child elements. I just needed to see the raw POST content temporarily while developing a webhook application.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve all the keys of the $_POST array using [array_keys()](http://php.net/function.array-keys), then construct an email messages with the values of those keys.

[var_dump($_POST)](http://php.net/function.var-dump) will also dump information about all of the information in $_POST for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_REQUEST` as well as `$_POST` to reach everything such as Post, Get and Cookie data.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the others, [var_export](http://php.net/var_export) might be handy too:

```
$email_text = var_export($_POST, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to echo all data of $_POST.

```php
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

You can also do this for more better viewing.

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```