# if(isset($_POST.... not being set with ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I'm having a `zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog` box send a form via ajax to my controller. However, when I test the controller for the presence of the post `if(isset($_POST['Item']))`. It isn't present and I don't really know why. I'm adapting this post `http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/145/cjuidialog-for-create-new-model/` to fit my own needs.

This is the form within the model:

```
<div class="form">

<form id="email-item-form" action="/www.mywebsite.ca/item/1/my-first-item" method="post">   <div id="email-item-success" class="label label-success"></div>
<div id="email-item-failure" class="label label-important"></div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="Item_email_item">Email this item to:</label>        <input placeholder="Send to..." name="Item[email_item]" id="Item_email_item" type="text" />        <div class="errorMessage" id="Item_email_item_em_" style="display:none"></div>   </div><!-- row -->
<div class="row">
    <label for="Item_email_item_sender">Email sent from:</label>    
    <input placeholder="Sent from..." name="Item[email_item_sender]" id="Item_email_item_sender" type="text" />        <div class="errorMessage" id="Item_email_item_sender_em_" style="display:none"></div>    </div><!-- row -->

<br />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionEmail($id)
{
        if(isset($_POST['Item']))
    {

              // Rest of code
            }
}
```

The data is being sent via `CHtml::ajax` and declaring `'type'=>'post'`. The process has been working in terms of sending the item id to the controller and sending back responses to the modal box. The problem has started since I tried to confirm the presence of `$_POST['Item']` in order to set `$model->attributes=$_POST['Item'];`

Any help in solving this would be great thank you.

**Update to show CHtml::ajax()**

```
var url = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("item/email", array("id"=>$model->id)); ?>';

<?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
        'url'=>'js:url',
        'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
....// Rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any inputs or other form data that are `name="Item"`. However, if you change your php code to look for the exact names of the form, it should find them:

```
public function actionEmail($id)
{
        if(isset($_POST['Item[email_item_sender]']))
    {

              // Rest of code
            }
}
```

Edit:

If you want to see all your post data for debugging purposes, you can use this code from [PHP: Possible to automatically get all POSTed data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334830/php-possible-to-automatically-get-all-posted-data)

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
```

Comment: You should be able to find the presence of the $_POST['Item'] regardless in Yii. I did update to check and nothing.

Comment: What did you get what you ran the foreach script?

Comment: Nothing was returned. undefined variable in my stack trace. `$_POST` was empty

Comment: Then the PHP file isn't receiving any data, and it's an issue with your javascript.

Comment: I've updated the code, I'e been using `'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",` to pass the data.

Comment: Think i've fixed it, corercted the id for serialize() - Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default jQuery sends AJAX requests by a GET. Try this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
    'url'=>'js:url',
    'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
    'type'=>'POST'
    ...
```