# Identifying if no radio buttons selected with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to write some code that will determine if no radio buttons are selected on a form

the form consists of many fields but have just included the radio buttons in form below

```
<form action="myPHPPage.php" method="post"> 

Value 1 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue1"> 
Value 2 <input type="radio" name="silver" value="myValue2">
Value 3 <input type="radio" name="gold" value="myValue3">

<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
```

then in the `myPHPPage.php` page I have something like below to assign the POST value to a variable:

```
if(!isset($_POST['basic'])) {
 $var = $_POST['basic'];};
 $someValue = $var;
}
```

But I want some code like: If no radio buttons selected $var = $someValue

Comment: you want prompt out eroor message?

Comment: don't we need to give same name for all radio in one group.

Comment: The name within your radio group needs to be the same. You can change the value's though as you'd like. That way your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS....you should have all radio button same NAME

```
<form action="myPHPPage.php" method="post"> 

    Value 1 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue1"> 
    Value 2 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue2">
    Value 3 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue3">

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">

</form>
```

here your php code on server after the submit is press

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) { //change index to submit button name

         if($_POST['basic'] == ''){ // if no button is selected then

         $var = $someValue;

         }//if ends here

        else
         { //if any of the radio is selected "if you don't want else so remove that"

         $var = $_POST['basic'];

        }//else ends here

    }//isset ends here
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `all-radio buttons` in a `group` like

```
Value 1 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="basic"> 
Value 2 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="silver">
Value 3 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="gold">
```

Then in **PHP**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['basic'])) { //remove ! from condition
      $var = $_POST['basic'];};
      echo $someValue = $var;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

// Handle Post
if (isset($_POST['send']))
{
    // Get Post Values
    $basic  = isset($_POST['basic'])  ? $_POST['basic']  : '';
    $silver = isset($_POST['silver']) ? $_POST['silver'] : '';
    $gold   = isset($_POST['gold'])   ? $_POST['gold']   : '';

    // Atleast one is selected
    if (!empty($basic) || !empty($silver) || !empty($gold))
    {
        echo 'You have made atleast one selection';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'You have not made any selection.';
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post"> 
Value 1 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue1"> 
Value 2 <input type="radio" name="silver" value="myValue2">
Value 3 <input type="radio" name="gold" value="myValue3">
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: If all `radio's` are not in a group, then using `radio's` in code make some sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using radio, all the names of `input radio` for that particular option should be same.

```
Value 1 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="basic"> 
Value 2 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="silver">
Value 3 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="gold">

<?php
if(isset($_POST['basic'])) 
{
  $var = $_POST['basic'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to know about radio button is that if they are reflecting the same attribute, they should have a same name.
Thus your form have to be changed like this.

```
  <form action="myPHPPage.php" method="post"> 

Value 1 <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="basic"> 
Value 2 <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="silver">
Value 3 <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="gold">

<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
```

Then you want to assign  a value if  no radio button is selected.
You can do the following:

```
$var="";
$someValue="abc";
    if(isset($_POST['radionName'])) {
 $var = $_POST['radionName'];// This means one radio button is selected, thus you have a value.
}
else{
$var=$someValue; // No radio button is selected, thus you can assign a default desired value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="myPHPPage.php" method="post">
```

if buttons are optional please make a group of radio button with name attribute value.

```
 Value 1 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue1"> 
 Value 2 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue2">
 Value 3 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue3">

 <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">

 Then use a php condition here.
 <?php


if(isset($_POST['basic'])) {
 $var = $_POST['basic'];};
 $someValue = $var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check all $_POST elements,than can compare name and their values.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
  echo "$key=$value";
}
```

[PHP: Possible to automatically get all POSTed data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334830/php-possible-to-automatically-get-all-posted-data)

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="myPHPPage.php" method="post"> 

   Value 1 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue1"> 
   Value 2 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue2">
   Value 3 <input type="radio" name="basic" value="myValue3">

   <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">

   <?php


    if(!isset($_POST['basic'])) {
     $var = $_POST['basic'];};
     $someValue = $var;


     Please Try this one
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. `if(!isset` stands for if the POST is not set. You are getting the value inside it's TRUE part, this will throw a WARNING. And the OP asked to set $var=$somevalue if the POST is not set. You are missing it.