# Convert unknown post data to array

Tags: php, http-post

This is my code

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch ($method) {
  case 'POST':
    rest_post();  
    break;
  case 'GET':
    rest_get();  
    break;
  default:
    rest_error();  
    break;
}

function rest_get(){
    $url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str($url, $get_array);
    print_r($get_array);
}

function rest_post(){
    // display post params as array
}
```

**HTTP GET**

`/index.php?q=hi&q2=hello`

Output:

```
Array
(
    [q] => hi
    [q2] => hello
)
```

I just like to do the same to HTTP POST but I don't have any idea how to it. For example I don't know what type of post data I will be getting.

Comment: Found this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334830/php-possible-to-automatically-get-all-posted-data. Now all I want is to convert it to array

Comment: why print_r($_POST) is not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it already. Thanks

```
function rest_post(){
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    parse_str($postdata, $get_array);
    print_r($get_array);
}
```