# Get post data without the name of the input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I do create a quizz where the questions are created dynamically, so I can't really know how much answsers the javascript is going to generate.

Sending the data through Ajax is not the problem, but when it came to the PHP I would like to get the data from the form and I'm used to do it with the $POST['toto']... But I don't know the id (names) of the inputs.

I thought 2 solutions,
Create one field each time containing the number of answers.
 Or using a cookie so i could do a loop in the php file...

Is there any better solution?

Thank you 
goldiman

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334830/php-possible-to-automatically-get-all-posted-data

Answer (score 4):

`$_POST` is an array. You can iterate through each value

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value; // one of the quiz answer
}
```