# How can I use $POST in PHP to automatically collect data from HTML5 inputs and send through e-mail?

Tags: php, html, email

I have a questionnaire with tons of input fields.  So far I started a PHP script to send it to my email which goes as follows.

```
<?php 

$First_Name= $_POST['First_Name'];
$Last_Name= $_POST['Last_Name'];
$E_Mail= $_POST['E_Mail'];
$FB_Name= $_POST['FB_Name'];
$Twitter_Name= $_POST['Twitter_Name'];
$Country= $_POST['Country'];
$State_Province= $_POST['State_Province'];
$City= $_POST['City'];
$Phone_01= $_POST['Phone_01'];
$Phone_02= $_POST['Phone_02'];
$Phone_03= $_POST['Phone_03'];
$How_did_you_hear_about_my_Company= $_POST['How_did_you_hear_about_my_Company'];
$Operating_your_Business= $_POST['Operating_your_Business'];
$Name_for_your_Business= $_POST['Name_for_your_Business'];
$Whats_the_name_of_your_Business= $_POST['Whats_the_name_of_your_Business'];
$What_type_of_Business= $_POST['What_type_of_Business'];
$Type_of_Business_you_run= $_POST['Type_of_Business_you_run'];
$How_long_you_been_building= $_POST['How_long_you_been_building'];
$How_long_you_been_in_business= $_POST['How_long_you_been_in_business'];
$What_do_you_plan_to_offer= $_POST['What_do_you_plan_to_offer'];
$What_do_you_offer= $_POST['What_do_you_offer'];
$List_all_products_you_offer['List_all_products_you_offer'];

$from = 'From: Your_New_Client';
$to = 'Optiqvision@gmail.com';
$subject = 'A New Questionnaire';

$body = "Name: $First_Name $Last_Name
\n E-Mail: $E_Mail
\n FB Name: $FB_Name
\n Twitter Name: $Twitter_Name
\n Country: $Country
\n State/Province: $State_Province
\n City: $City
\n Phone Number: $Phone_01 $Phone_02 $Phone_03
\n How did you hear about my Company?:\n\n $How_did_you_hear_about_my_Company
\n Where are you in terms of opperating your Business?: $Operating_your_Business
\n Have you come up with a name for your Business?: $Name_for_your_Business
\n What's the name of your Business?: $Whats_the_name_of_your_Business
\n What type of Business will you be running?: $What_type_of_Business
\n What type of Business do you run?: $Type_of_Business_you_run
\n How long have you been Building your Business?: $How_long_you_been_building
\n How long have you been in Business?: $How_long_you_been_in_business
\n What do you plan to offer?: $What_do_you_plan_to_offer
\n What do you offer?: $What_do_you_offer
\n List of products: $List_all_products_you_offer 
";

?>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
}
?>
```

This works properly, but I want to know how I can tell the PHP to automatically collect all the data without me having to go one by one with each element (there's a lot more than what's represented above).

I came across a script that does this for storing to an SQL database, but not one for email.  I tried using the one for SQL but was running into issues because of how many columns it creates.

Aside from this I have another task to tackle with allowing users to add fields which will vary from user to user, so I need the $POST method to be flexible so it can send the results.  With the way I have it coded so far, there's no way for extra fields to be posted when the user adds them.

I searched through the site and so far this is the only thing I've come across that relates to this issue, but don't really understand what's being said. [PHP: Possible to automatically get all POSTed data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334830/php-possible-to-automatically-get-all-posted-data)

If that is indeed the answer to what I'm trying to do could someone please break it down a little more and tell me how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
$body="";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $body.= str_replace("_"," ",$key).": ". $value."\n";
}
```

provided that `$key` holds the descriptive information which you need with words separated by underscore (_) as in your question is.

Comment: SPLENDID IT WORKS!!!!!  The only thing is the <br/> shows up in the email rather than starting a new line, so it's all one long paragraph.

Comment: replace `<br/>` with `\n`. If you want to use `<br/>`, you need to specify `content-type` header