# Pass variable via ajax to api.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a js variable via ajax to the php side. My js code is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var sAgentId = 'hi'
  $.ajax({
    url: "api-test.php",
    method: "POST",
    data : { id:sAgentId}
  }).done(function(){
    console.log('done')  
  })
```

and in the php file, I am trying to get the variable via post:

```
$sAgentId = $_POST['id'];
```

But finally in api i get the notification that says

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev-php-exam-prep\exercise\api-test.php on line 2

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you getting this error ? Using ajax or directly browsing to `api-test.php` ?

Comment: The code you've shown should work. Have you tried checking to see all the data that's posted? You can see how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334830/php-possible-to-automatically-get-all-posted-data/12618730)

Comment: I tried to see all the data that is posted. But it seems that there is no posted data. I used '$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $postdata;' and I dont have any errors but the echo is empty

Comment: Can you try $postData = $_POST;

Comment: how do you call the ajax function?

Comment: Does your api expect `id` or `sAgentId` parameter ?

Comment: Your title says `api.php`. Your script says `api-test.php`. Which is it?

Comment: Also try to first call `method: 'POST',` and then `url: 'api-test.php',`

Comment: how should I call the ajax function?

Comment: For example by clicking on a button

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your AJAX method:

`dataType: "json"`

Try also console logging the response back to check $_POST['id'] is being set.

```
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("Data: ", data);
});
```

and in your PHP just return $_POST['id']

Comment: `dataType` is used for type of datas of the API **response**

Answer (score 0):

```
  var sAgentId = 'hi' 
    $.ajax({
        url:'api-test.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: sAgentId },
        cache: !0,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try replace method by type:

```
  type: "POST",
```

Comment: Only if  you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: "An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.".  Unless OP is stuck in the stone age, it's probably not it.

Comment: Check the question : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` OP is using JQuery 3.4.1

Comment: I'm sorry, how to get 50 reputations?

Comment: @PhiCuong [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is how you get reputation