# How to update multiple rows using array

Tags: php

I have this form

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<td>Category Name</td>
<td> <input type="text" value=""  class="form-control"  name="eids[<?php echo $id?>]"></td>
</tr>
```

And here is how i update

```
include "config.php";
foreach($_POST['eids'] as $key=>$value){ 
    $updateq=$conn->prepare("UPDATE  `table_name` SET table_row='$value' WHERE sn='$key'");
    $updateq->execute();
    }
```

When I submit let say three records ie(A,B,C) Table updated like this (C,C,C). Please help

Comment: Hello, what do you mean A,B,C, i see a single input here?

Comment: Basically keep the name the same and put the unknown in the `value` attribute `<input type="text" name="eids[]" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $id?>]">` See the DUP For more details

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on this page:

[PHP: Possible to automatically get all POSTed data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334830/php-possible-to-automatically-get-all-posted-data/12618730)

i found this:

Sure. Just walk through the $_POST array:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I got this error: Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string,