# AJAX Post, Codeigniter 4 /PHP - The controller is not catching the posted data

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have the below ajax js.  I am trying to make a POST to my controller with the `id` .  In the line starting with `let id ...` when I log it to console, I can see the `id` number but the controller doesn't receive it.  Also in XHR/payload I see [object Object] which do not know why.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-task', function(event){
    // id comes from data-id
    let id = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        url:  ajaxUrl+'/admin/tasks/delete',
        type: 'POST',
        // what data you passing.
        data: {
            'id' : id
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Route is;  `$routes->match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/tasks/delete', 'Admin\Task\Task_Controller::task_delete');`

For my controller, I have the below.  As it is a post, I expect to be able to get the `id` by using `$this->request->getVar('id')` but doesn't work.  I always get 'success' => '0 'msg' => "No Task To Delete" returned.  Any pointers appreciated.

````
```
public function task_delete(){
    $id = $this->request->getVar('id');
    if(empty($id)){
        $response = [
            'success' => 0,
            'msg' => "No Task To Delete",
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $task = new TaskModel();
        $task->task_delete($id);
        $response = [
            'success' => 1,
            'msg' => "Task Deleted",
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}```
````

So I can see id=103 in the payload in the console but for somereason but reaching the controller.  Interesting also is when I log log_message('error', $request->getMethod()); it is a critical error as blank.  Even log_message('error', $request->isAjax()); is critical error as blank.

Comment: Why are you appending the id value to the route URL, when you say you want to send it via POST?

Comment: Ok, I mixed up two patterns.  Thanks for spotting.  I have removed /'+id, and changed my routes to not expect a number in the URL.  It still comes back "no task to delete" and Request Payload shows;  [object Object]  for some reason.

Comment: Show us your route definitions in `app\Config\Routes.php`. In addition, show us, the output of `$this->request->getPost()`. Lastly, show us the output of `$this->request->getPath()`

Comment: _"Request Payload shows; [object Object] for some reason"_ - probably due to `processData: false`.

Comment: Here is the route:  $routes->match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/tasks/delete', 'Admin\Task\Task_Controller::task_delete');  Here is the output of $this->request->getPath()/ getPost() which captures in ci4 logs. getPost -> ERROR - 2022-06-20 09:09:51 --> 
getPath -> ERROR - 2022-06-20 09:09:51 --> admin/tasks/delete

Comment: I change processData to true.  I can now see id=103 (example) in the payload window but doesn't get to controller for some reason.

Comment: Unless you're sending/submitting [multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean), you *shouldn't* be using [`processData: false`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20data%20passed%20in%20to%20the%20data%20option%20as%20an%20object)

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72683513/edit) and show us your HTML form snippet where you define the `data-id` HTML element attribute. In addition, please remove the [`processData: false`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20data%20passed%20in%20to%20the%20data%20option%20as%20an%20object) and [`contentType: false` declarations](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#:~:text=When%20sending%20data%20to%20the%20server%2C%20use%20this%20content%20type) from the AJAX settings and try again.

Comment: The payload is being sent, eg, id=103.  For info, the id in the table is being generated by javascript in datatables but I dont think the error is there.  Here it is though:          "columns": [
            {"data":null,
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return '<i class="fas delete-task fa-edit" data-id="'+data.id+'"></i> '+data.id+' | <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
                }
            },

Comment: Inside your controller, can you log a `var_dump` of the `$request` object and post the contents? That might help.

Comment: As it is an sqyncronis request, I put this in my method in my controller:  log_message('error', print_r(var_dump($request)));  It just returns 1.  Same with $_POST... maybe there is a better way to see info?

Comment: If I comment out dataType: 'json', I can see a lot of info in the console.  This is shown;   ["body":protected]=>
  string(6) "id=103"
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(17) {
    ["Content-Type"]=

Comment: @spreaderman Passing a `var_dump` output to `print_r` is redundant and you're missing the second parameter to `print_r` anyways: `log_message('error', print_r($request, TRUE));`

Comment: @parttimeturtle thank you for your explanation. I have added that line but the $request is blank as follow;  ERROR - 2022-06-23 00:33:24 -->

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$_POST array empty in PHP after an a request with post data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33961235/7376590)

Comment: Where are you defining that variable `$request` from? Do you intend to mean `log_message('error', json_encode($this->request));`

Comment: sorry, huge dump json_encode($this->request)); but no id 103 anywhere in the dump.              [get] => Array
                (
                )

            [post] => Array
                (
                )

Comment: Do you still have the AJAX configurations for `processData` and `contentType` as they are in the question? If that isn't the case, please update your question.