# Pass value of html to PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some trouble passing the value of some HTML elements to PHP variable. I have a PHP web app where I give the users some drop down option. What I want to do is after the user has selected the option I give than to click on a button and make some calculations based on his/her selection.

I have tried using the POST and GET method but because I'm new to php I probably did it wrong. I also try with ids but no results.

Here is the HTML code
The 1st dropdown menu :

```
<div>
   <select id="kleidwma" onchange="kleidwmata_change(this.value);kwdikos();ypsos();" 
       class="form-control selectpicker kleidwmata" data-size="10"  data- 
       style="btn-white" name="guard_kleidwmata" required  >

       <option value="" >&nbsp;</option>
       <option value="12">12 MS</option>
       <option value="14">14 KETE</option>
       <option value="15">15 ARRIKTON</option>
       <option value="16">16 KETE</option>
       <option value="22">22 KETE</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

The 2nd dropdown menu :

```
<div>
    <select id="sigkratisi" onchange="kwdikos()" name="sigkratisi" 
        class="form-control sigkratisi" required>

        <option value="" ></option>
    <option value="metalliki" >Μεταλλική</option>
    <option value="xilogonia" >Ξυλογωνία</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Here is the button to be clicked after the selection has been made :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left: 235px;">
    <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="hidden" name="tmp_calculate" value="pending" />
    <button onclick="calculate()" type="button" class="btn btn-success" > 
    <?php echo "Υπολογισμός";?></button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And finally here is the function that is called :

```
function calculate()
{
    $var1 =   sigkratisi;
    $var2 =   kleidwma;
        "code to be executed base on the var1 and var2"
}
```

I hope it's clear enough.
Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: You can't pass data directly html to php. You have to call ajax get/post request from html to php. then php return calculated data to your ajax success method. after you can print your calculated data inside html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all variables sent with POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207488/get-all-variables-sent-with-post)

Comment: Any hint how may i achieve that or where to look, thanks

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to calculate once the user has selected the options. Is it just a basic calculation that could be completed client side, or are you using the information selected to get more information from a database etc? Your post doesn't make it clear.

Comment: I will only use the selected options, no need to access any database

Comment: If I knew what sort of calculation you wanted to perform on the input or selection variables, then it could be done in javascript, without any need for PHP.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Forms

```
<form name="f" action="" method="POST">
<div>
<select id="kleidwma" name="variable" 
   class="form-control selectpicker kleidwmata" data-size="10"  data- 
   style="btn-white" name="guard_kleidwmata" required  >
   <option value="" >&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="12">12 MS</option>
   <option value="14">14 KETE</option>
   <option value="15">15 ARRIKTON</option>
   <option value="16">16 KETE</option>
   <option value="22">22 KETE</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

in PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['variable']))
{
echo $_POST['variable'];
}
?>
```