# PHP How to filter 'in a correct way' All $_POST variables

Tags: php, post, netbeans, filter

Using Netbeans, whenever i try to access a variable in $_POST or $_GET, i'm adviced to use something like: `filter_input(INPUT_POST,'id')`, for 'safety' (i don't think it's any safer than using filter_input with the default NON filter, but anyways..).

This got me thinking about the answer to this post: [How to grab all variables in a post (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058336/how-to-grab-all-variables-in-a-post-php)

There you have:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //do something
    echo $key . ' has the value of ' . $value;
}
```

filter_input() only works for individual variables inside $_POST

My question is, How can i re-write "`$_POST as $key`" with filtering to fit this supposed access standard that NetBeans is telling me about?.

Comment: You know, you can turn off that warning in Netbeans.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i know, i can also cross the street without looking at the traffic lights

Comment: The thing is, without knowing the specific type of filter you need, you'll just have to use "the default non filter" anyway, which isn't any safer than just turning off the warning. If you _do_ know what types of filters you need, then filter_input_array will actually be useful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can filter whole `$_POST` using [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)

```
$safePost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
```

Using the second parameter you can change filter

```
$safePost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

You can also define per-property filters

```
$safePost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
    "id" => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    "name" => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    "email" => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
]);
```

---

> What if I know nothing about input?

You always know something, you know what you expect to get.
If the user provides an invalid input you should react to that.

If you expect an integer in the `id` field and the user sends you `tomato`, then you should reply with an error informing the user what is wrong with the request they sent.

Comment: How would you address the situation in mentioned in the "How to grab all variables in a post (PHP)" post, about unknown variable names and quantities, for example i could have "id","name","email1","email2"...."email.......X". How could i filter those with this function

Comment: @ndelucca you can use single argument call `$safePost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);`, you will get all variables from POST

Comment: @ndelucca that is true, it will use `FILTER_DEFAULT` which means don't filter at all but NB should stop complaining. If you know nothing about your expected input you can't properly filter/sanitize it, if you do know something then filter using call with 2 parameters

Comment: @mleko can you help me buddy ? i m in same kind of situation. my `$_POST` is multimentional array, it has multiple arrays like  `$_POST[array1], $_POST[array2], $_POST[array3], $_POST[array4] .....` each array consists of some string variables. how can i filter this post array ?

Comment: @santosh If I understand you correctly. You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php. e.g. `$safePost = filter_var($_POST['key1']['key2']);` If this is not what you need, please provide more details or some example

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```php
        $methods = (string)$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        $vars_dl = [];

        if( in_array( $methods, ['POST', 'GET'] ) ) {

            switch( $methods ) {

                case 'POST':

                    $post_vars = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS | FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY ) ?? [];

                    $vars_dl = [ $post_vars, 'p' ];

                    break;

                case 'GET':

                    $get_vars = filter_input_array( INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS | FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY ) ?? [];

                    $vars_dl = [ $get_vars, 'g' ]; 

                    break;

            }

        }
        else {

            exit('<h1>ACCESS Exception :: method '. $methods .' blocked!</h1>');

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map()` function to apply custom filter function to all array values of posted data:

```
$_POST['Users'] = array_map('clean_string', $_POST['Users']);
```

And here is the snipped of `clean_string()`function:

```
<?php 
function clean_string($string, $mode = "strip") {       
        switch ($mode) {
                //Keep characters like é and д
                default:
                case "strip":
                $filter = array("flags"=> FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK);
                break;
                //Keep characters like é and д
                case "encode":
                $filter = array("flags"=> FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP); 
                break;
        }
        return filter_var(trim($string), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, $filter);      
    }
```