# How to fetch the only $_POST value

Tags: php, forms, post, filter

I'm trying to assign to a variable the unique index that is in $_POST.

I'm trying to do this, because the $_POST value will change for each button I press, and doing them all is like too long, plus, it's like a filer, every time you add a file, 3 new buttons appear, so too long.

The value either starts with 'edit', 'download', or 'delete', followed by the id of the selected file. For example, the 8th file will be deleted with 'delete8'.

I used filter to fetch the file id in my php file, but I can do it, only when I know exactly how the value is named.

Is there a way to select automatically the one and only value available in $_POST ?

Comment: adding code which re-creates the issue would greatly help

Comment: XY Problem, you should be doing `name="delete[]" value="8"` and looping over the array of `$_POST['delete']` instead. Same with the download, and edit would just be a link :/

Comment: if you want to filter the whole `$_POST` without knowing the variable name, see [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165533/php-how-to-filter-in-a-correct-way-all-post-variables). Then to get the only value, simply do a `foreach` on it and do a `break;` just after retreiving the first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_keys` will give you an array of keys in an array.

```
$name = array_keys($_POST)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use,

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
 $posteddata[$key]=$value;
}
```

for fetching posted data

```
<input type="text" name="n1">
<input type="text" name="n2">
echo $posteddata['n1'];
echo $posteddata['n2'];
```