# Cannot access html form data in a post message (PHP)

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying out a php sample code given here:  https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

This gives a log in form, where you can register username password and then log in with a registered user. A welcome page is only visible after you have logged in, and the welcome page shows the specific username of the currently logged in account.

I am trying to modify the welcome.php given in the above link, to add a data entry form that will save some personal data like name and age to a mariadb database. Here is my version of the welcome.php file:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

$uname=htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]);
$name = "";
$age = 0;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // /*
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("submit button clicked")';
    echo '</script>';
    // */
    // /*
    $tempvar = trim($_POST["name"]);
    // $tempvar='sdsd';
    var_dump($tempvar);
    if($tempvar == "")
        echo $tempvar.' found';
    // */
}

?>

 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b>. Welcome to our site.</h1>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-warning">Reset Your Password</a>
        <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
    </p>
    <p>Enter your data here:</p>
    <!-- <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post"> -->
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit">
        <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit"> -->
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

If I understand this correctly clicking the submit button should generate a post message which should be captured by the php script at the beginning of the file. This much is happening, but I cannot display the content of the text box given by `<input type="text" name="name">`. The `var_dump($tempvar);` in the php code at the beginning comes up with `String(0) ""`. I have tried moving the php code to a separate file (as given [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-insert-query.php) in insert.php) instead of attempting to process the post message in the same file, but I am getting the same result. I am not getting any errors.

How do I access the contents of the text box in the post message handler? I am testing this in XAMPP on Windows 10.

Comment: You have multiple logical errors

Comment: This line here `if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true)` will run second condition even it `loggedin` key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the example with the login work correctly? This would prove that `POSTing` data works.

Which version of PHP are you using? There was a feature called [`register_globals`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) up to `5.4.0` which allowed accessing `POST` data via named variables. Since you are setting `$name = ""` this could overwrite your data. I would take it out at that position anyway (use an else clause if necessary). If you have `register_globals` active either update PHP or turn it off to avoid confusion.

The next step to debug the issue is to print the whole array of `$_POST` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3058351/14141116) but more pretty

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
```

This will show you what values were actually `POSTed`.

Same can be done with the `$_SERVER` array like this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
echo '</pre>';
die();
$uname=htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]);
```

The `die()` command will halt execution so you need to remove it when you want the script to continue.

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` should come without conditional for debugging

Comment: why the downvote? Please explain in order to improve my answer

Comment: @GetSet what do you mean? For simple debugging purposes i think putting a `print_r` into the code is very reasonable. After all this seems like a learning experience so pointing towards basic means of debugging is probably the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. I ran it in my system, it shows the submitted name with the `var_dump` i.e. **string(18) "Md Shabbir Hossain"**.

Comment: Are you using XAMPP? Which php version are you using? Did tihs exact same code work for you or did you modify anything?

Comment: I'm using wamp and php=5.3.0.
I removed your session_start and isset_session part. But the main part is okay.

Answer (score 0):

There are some flaws that I would fix.

Initial user get to Welcome.php.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

$uname=htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); //username is not defined or it does not exists yet.
$name = "";
$age = 0;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // /*
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("submit button clicked")';
    echo '</script>';
    // */
    // /*
    $tempvar = trim($_POST["name"]);
    // $tempvar='sdsd';
    var_dump($tempvar);
    if($tempvar == "")
        echo $tempvar.' found';
    // */
}
```

I would do this:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 //Check if the user already logged.
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])){
    //Redirect
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

// Check if post to login is submitted
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
  // /*
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("submit button clicked")';
    echo '</script>';
  $uname = '';
  //Check if Username is submitted
  if(isset($_POST['username'])){
     $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['username'];
     $uname=htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]);
  }
  $name = "";
  $age = 0;
  

  //For test
  var_dump($_POST[]);
}
```

Comment: this is welcome.php. The login part is working. I want to modify welcome.php for a logged in user to be able to use the data entry form and add things to the database

Comment: This is really not meter at all, the logged user should have a session var initiated. if it is not, then it should go to login page. it is just example.

Comment: if user is not logged in it already goes to login page

Comment: i saw, i fixed.